# Getting a USB turntable to be detected on Windows or Mac

Tags: windows, mac, usb, audio

I have a SoundLab G056C USB turntable but I'm having trouble finding out how to get it to work with Audacity. For one thing I can't detect it in Windows or Mac - I'm told it comes up with the usual "drivers installing" popup but that doesn't happen on the Windows or Mac laptop I've plugged it into. One thing is that it's plugged straight into the computer using a USB cable - I don't think it needs a pre-amp but I don't know that for sure (the manual says just plug it in).

Does anyone have any experience with this model, or any general advice to get this to be detected? Once it's 'there' I can get Audacity to work with it no problem :)

Comment: What version of audacity are you using ?

Comment: 1.3.13 Beta on Windows and 1.2.5 on Mac - I'm confused as the device isn't detected.

Comment: On a quick google search, someone else found they had just wired it improperly. Just run a check that your connections are good again.

Comment: If you don't even get a detection in Windows (you know, the usual sound), or it doesn't show up in the device manager, @Simon is probably right and the connection itself is faulty.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try that shortly. Apparently it has worked before, but blew a fuse when plugged into a laptop that was charging (sounds dubious but it still works when plugged into speakers so we'll see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing I think the blown fuse by someone else has broken the turntable internally. As a solution I am using a USB->AUX adapter (which is essentially the same thing).

[image]